# Trying to switch from 2.4 to 5 GHz

Tags: networking

I am running a RT3092 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R PCIe vendor: Ralink is there a way to change frequency to 5GHz ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have WiFi where the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz are using the same SSID and you want the OS to choose which frequency to use?  You could just change the SSID names on the router so they aren't the same.

Comment: i believe i changed the name of the 5 g but it doesnt show up to connect to but i know its enabled the router says so its a century link c4000xg    but im not sure how to get the computer to detect the other network it only sees the 2.4 conection ? sorry about the punctuation lol im not much of a typer

Comment: i am using ubuntu 20.04 btw if that helps any

Comment: Do you have any other devices that see both?  The router may need a hard reboot for the SSID to display properly.

Comment: Also try it up close to the router.  In general, 5Ghz has a shorter range. I have a Nighthawk X6, one of the two 5Ghz bands only has a range of about 10 feet, the other I can't get good reception in the whole house.  The 2.4Ghz reaches 200 ft away from the house.

Answer (score 0):

- Pull up your network connections UI.
- Select the WiFi connection.
- In the WiFi tab, there is the option `band` which defaults to Automatic.
- Change this to 5Ghz.

Alternatively, on your router, change the SSID of each to distinguish them at the name level.  This can be beneficial for a few reasons.  It will allow you to choose a specific band on routers with more than two bands (I have two 5Ghz bands, there is no way to distinguish them in Ubuntu).  Some people can have issues with one of the bands and it prevents them from connecting to any of them when the names are same (My 2.4Ghz will sometimes start dropping devices for no reason and it would not switch to 5Ghz, changing the names allowed it to fail over at the connection level instead of the band level.  A hard reboot fixes it but that requires getting up).